# GCM message not recieving in lollipop devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working on a chat based application using Google cloud Messaging.

The GCM message triggers fine with kitkat version, jellybean version devices.

But in lollipop devices its not working.

Comment: Since lolipop the notification looks little different, but I didn't notice any problem with receving pushes and imo it haven't got any influance on sending mechanism. Maybe give some more details, what kind of message GCM returns to you, when you lunch push sending script? There should be some information. Are you using php to send message?

Comment: Can you show some logs which are from server or client side to prove something you are not receiving?

Comment: Which GCM SDK version you are using ?